# How do I call "operator->()" directly?

Tags: c++

For some strange reason, I need to call the operator->() method directly. For example:

```
class A {
    public:
        void foo() { printf("Foo"); }
};

class ARef {
    public:
        A* operator->() { return a; }
    protected:
        A* a;
};
```

If I have an ARef object, I can call foo() by writing:

```
aref->foo();
```

However, I want to get the pointer to the protected member 'a'. How can I do this?

Comment: The title of your question states that you want to call the `operator->` directly. The body of the questions states that you want to obtain a pointer to `ARef::a`. These are two completely unrelated issues. So, what is it you want to ask about? If you see a connection between the two, please, explain it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
aref.operator->(); // Returns A*
```

Note that this syntax works for all other operators as well:

```
// Assuming A overloads these operators
A* aref1 = // ...
A* aref2 = // ...
aref1.operator*();
aref1.operator==(aref2);
// ...
```

For a cleaner syntax, you can a implement a `Get()` function or overload the `*` operator to allow for `&*aref` as suggested by [James McNellis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3398825/how-do-i-call-operator-directly/3398843#3398843).

Answer (score 5):

You can call the operator directly using the following syntax:

```
aref.operator->()
```

You should probably overload both `->` and `*`, so that usage is consistent with the usage of a pointer:

```
class ARef {
    public:
        A* operator->() { return a; }
        A& operator*() { return *a; }
    protected:
        A* a;
};
```

Then you can use the following to get the pointer value:

```
&*aref
```

You can also implement a `get()` member function that returns the `A*` directly, which is much, much cleaner than either of these solutions (most smart pointer classes provide a `get()` member function).

Comment: I usually implement `get()` as a friend function defined in the smart pointer class itself (e.g. `GetRawPtr(ptr);`), because it's rather odd to see `ptr->FooBar()` and then see `ptr.get()` somewhere else.

Answer (score 3):

You can call `operator->()` directly.

```
A* result = a.operator->();
```

Answer (score 2):

I would probably not call it together, but instead create a new member which does the same work since it would read better:

```
class ARef {
public:
    A* operator->() { return get(); }
    A* get() const { return a; }
protected:
    A* a;
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Absent any friends, you cannot get a "pointer to the protected member `a`" outside class `A` or one of its descendants. Operator `->` will not help you here, regardless of how you call it.

Given the current interface of `ARef`, the only way to get a pointer to `a` is to do something like `A **pa = &a` inside one of the methods of class `A` or some descendant class.

I don't know why you need to get a pointer to `a`, and frankly it doesn't seem to make much practical sense to me, but if you really need it, you can add a separate method that does exactly that

```
class ARef {
public:
  ...
  A** get_ptr_to_a() { return &a; }
  ...
};
```